# Displaying message status: read and unread (differs from other users) in PHP/MySQL messaging system

Tags: php, mysql, messaging

I am displaying the message status that differs from each user. Let's say `user1` sends a message to `user2`, `user1`'s message status then sets to `read`, while `user2`'s message is set to `unread` by default. It will be updated after `user2` clicks the message.

So in these scenario, the message of `user1` (from the inbox) will have a gray-colored font which indicates that the message is set to `read` (since `user1` is the one who is sending). On the other side, `user2` have a bold font that indicates that the message is `unread`.

Here is the first structure of the table:

```
message(messageid, fromid, toid, message, timestamp, status)
```

The problem here is that if I update the message status to `read`, it affects the other side (`user2`). So I add another column that will set the status differently from `user1` and `user2`:

```
message(messageid, fromid, toid, message, timestamp, from_status, to_status)
```

Here, `from_status` is for the `fromid` and `to_status` is for `toid`. But I'm having a problem on how to use these values to display the status.

The PHP code of that I use during my first attempt is these:

```
<?php 
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT m.* FROM message m
                                  LEFT JOIN message m2 ON (
                                  (m.fromid=m2.fromid AND m.toid=m2.toid) OR
                                  (m.fromid=m2.toid AND m.toid=m2.fromid)
                                  ) AND m.timestamp<m2.timestamp
                                  WHERE (m.fromid='$id' OR m.toid='$id') AND m2.toid IS NULL ORDER BY timestamp DESC");

while ($message = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  if ($message['status'] === 'unread') {
    // bold font style will be applied
  }
  else {
    // gray-colored font will be applied
  }
}
?>
```

(The query fetches each conversation from every user with the latest conversation.)

These code works fine for the main user, which is `user1`, but affects the other side, which views that the message received from `user2` is set to `read` instead or `unread`.

So, I'm having some trouble on what to do on the modified table, having 2 separate `status` each for each user. How can I get these done?

Comment: Is there an option to re-set the status to unread? Because otherwise, you can just assume that if the person looking at the message is the sender, it'll be read, and have a single status field that tracks whether the recipient has read it.

Comment: For a slightly better solution, rename the fields to `sender_status` and `recipient_status`, so it's clear which is which, and just update the appropriate one depending on who is reading the message right now

Comment: For a more elegant solution, amend the database so that there's a new table for message recipients, with fields like 'usedID', 'status' and 'role', where role is 'sender' or recipient'. That will let you send the same message to multiple people, and track each of their statuses individually.

Comment: @andrewsi
Would that reset the status of `user2` too?

Comment: Not necessarily. So long as each status is stored separately, you can update them individually if you want to

Comment: @andrewsi
I will keep the `message` table and add the `message_recipients` table?

Comment: Hi there. @GhostGambler removed the [solved] title tag for good reason, we don't do that here. I have additionally moved the appended answer to a wiki-style answer - if you wish to add your own answers please use the answer box in future. Also, if a high rep user edits your post, please contact them before reverting their edit - they may have knowledge about style and formatting that you do not. I have additionally removed the 'snippet' feature from your code blocks, since SQL/PHP won't run inside the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@andrewsi comment is quite nice, when you'll have for example many receivers. In your case it's only one additional field, so in my opinion it's not an overflow to use just one table.
Regarding your case you can do this in one simple sql:

```
SELECT m.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN m.fromid = $id THEN m.from_status 
        WHEN m.toid = $id THEN m.to_status
    END as read_status
FROM message m
WHERE
    m.fromid = $id OR m.toid = $id
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

And in your view you are only checking the *read_status* field

Comment: I kinda understand these now. I tested the query and gives me the message status. All I need is to implement it. Thanks.

Comment: I will implement it first, and I will mark it once I've make it work. You have my word. Do you mind upvoting my question to so it can reach other programmers who might encounter the same problem as mine? It will be a big help. :)

Comment: I have another question. These part only solves the portion of my problem. My inbox is grouped by the sender, the `from`, given from the query above on my php code. How do I modify these? Also it should display the latest conversation.

Comment: Oh, don't mind. I managed to solved it using some part of your code. You have my thanks mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP.)*

I've managed to solve the problem, thanks to @Rafal Mnich. So I grab a part of his query and do a bit of modification, and it works.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT m.msgid, m.fromid, m.toid, m.content,
  CASE
    WHEN m.fromid = '$id' THEN m.frommsgstatus
    WHEN m.toid = '$id' THEN m.tomsgstatus
  END AS msgstatus
FROM msg m
  LEFT JOIN msg m2
    ON ((m.fromid=m2.fromid AND m.toid=m2.toid) OR (m.fromid=m2.toid AND m.toid=m2.fromid)) AND m.timestamp<m2.timestamp
WHERE (m.fromid='$id' OR m.toid='$id') AND m2.toid IS NULL
ORDER BY m.timestamp DESC
```

These displays the messages grouped by the sender `fromid`, which also displays the latest conversation you have from each of the senders. And it displays the correct message status in both sides of the users.

Comment: But why do you need this left join?

Comment: Hi @RafałMnich, you'll need to post that under the question after it is unlocked - I posted this on behalf of the OP, having taken the text from a solution appended to the question.

Comment: @RafałMnich: the question is now unlocked, so you can post that under the question if you wish.